# Compound interest with adding money each year

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, finance

I am trying to figure out this question in python, I found the compound interest rate formula however, for me the biggest problem is how to add 50 dollars after each year after my money increased by interest rate

```
Principal(Starting amount) is: 100 USD
Yearly Interest rate: 10 percent
after each year-end, we add 50 USD.

How much our money will be after 3 years?


def compound_interest(p,r,n,t):
    a = p * (1 + r/n)**t
    return a
```

```
Thank you so much for your help from now!
```

Answer (score 1):

```
capital = 100
ir = 0.1
bonus = 50

def compound_interest(year, capital, ir, bonus):
  if year == 0:
    return capital
  
  investment_return = (capital * ir) + bonus

  return compound_interest(year - 1, capital + investment_return, ir, bonus)

print(compound_interest(0, capital, ir, bonus))
print(compound_interest(1, capital, ir, bonus))
print(compound_interest(2, capital, ir, bonus))
```